# Cassandra Materialized Views

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views

I have few queries related to the materialized views(MV) in Cassandra 3.x version. Given below is  my understanding of how materialized views work. Can anyone please tell me if my understanding is correct

1.) MV is a replica of a base table. Say I have a base table with 100 GB of data and my replication factor is 3. MV on the base table is nothing but another table with a different partition occupying the same storage as that of the base table. If I am creating an MV for my above table, I will need an addition of 100GB * 3(replication factor)  for storing the new materialized view data?

2.) If the above case is valid, then as such there will be two write process happening for the same data. In case of INSERT, there will be a WRITE overhead, since data will be inserted both to the table and the MV? In case of updates, there will be a read before write on the MV?

3.) The changes to MV when a base table changes will happen asynchornously? What happens if the entire table data is deleted, will it be reflected in MV's immediately or is there some cleanup we need to take?

4.) Any scenarios which needs to be considered where use of MV's could be avoided?

Please help me in clarifying the above questions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Materialized views handle automated server-side denormalization, removing the need for client side handling of this denormalization and ensuring eventual consistency between the base and view data. This denormalization allows for very fast lookups of data in each view using the normal Cassandra read path

Your Questions Answered below :

1. If you used `select *` when creating MV it will take addition of 100GB * 3 storage
2. The base replica performs a local read of the data in order to create the correct update for the view and use batchlog to provide an equivalent eventual consistency between base table and view. So Each MV will cost you about 10% performance at write time
3. It will reflected immediately and cassandra will take care of that cleanup.
4. When not to use MV :

   - Low cardinality data will create hotspots around the ring
     If the partition key of all of the data is the same, those nodes would become overloaded
   - If there will be a large number of partition tombstones, the performance may suffer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications. It helps.